# Amend CSS of Wordpress Plugin?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using WordPress, a Forum plugin and a Syntax Highlighter plugin.

At the moment the Syntax Highlighter styles render fine in a 'native' WordPress post/page.  However they don't render correctly on the Forum plugin pages.  This is due to the Forum CSS overriding some of the Syntax Highlighter CSS.

Consider this 'simplified' example: https://jsfiddle.net/2vkzx1js/

```
<div id="forum">
  <div class="post">
      <div class="syntaxhighlighter">
          <span>This should be red</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
      <div>
          <span>This should be blue</span>
      </div>      
  </div>
  <div class="post">
      <div>
          <span>This should be blue</span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
#forum .post span
{
    color:blue;
}

.syntaxhighlighter span {
  color:red;
}
```

I know that if I add '#forum' to the start of the CSS declarations in the Syntax Highlighter plugin it would render ok:

```
#forum .syntaxhighlighter span {
  color:red;
}
```

But I don't want to start overwriting plugin files for obvious reasons.

What are the most feasible options to fix this?

Comment: You could copy the CSS to your style.css and make the modifications. You can also find the CSS being called by the plugin and use `wp_dequeue_style` in your themes `functions.php`, so your not doubling up on CSS.

Comment: This option probably appears to be the most favourable, avoiding duplicate CSS.  I'll have a look into it and report back if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make modifications to the plugin css files, you can just make those modifications in your own custom css file. The problem, as you've already discovered, is the selector process. You can just remove `#forum` from the first line and it works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vuc6ybt4/

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately the '#forum' selectors are part of the Forum plugin CSS files, so it's a similar predicament.

Comment: @Captain_Planet right but can’t you just use the solution you discovered above by loading a custom css file after the plugin css file and overriding those rules? No need to change the plugin source.

Comment: I could, but I'd end up with lots of duplicated CSS (there's a lot of CSS, not just a small amount in this simplified example).  So I'm going to look at the dequeue option, and then add the styles in my theme....